# bootstrap div margin top

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, margin

I need to have a `margin top` in the `class` property of the `div`. How can I do it?

```
<div class="mb-md-3  ml-md-3   col-lg-8" >
          <!-- <div class="mb-md-3  ml-md-3   col-lg-8" > -->
                <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/admin/add_hospital">
                  <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="add_hospital()">
                    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add Hospital
                  </button>
                </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you give a better explanation of what your goal is?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see of:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

It looks like `mb` and `ml` referrs to `margin-bottom` and `margin-left`

I'm no Bootstrap expert but maybe you could try with something like `mt-0`

As for the class:

```
.mt-0 {
     margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

Should set the Margin top to 0, else just make your own class with the important attribute

Edit:

Looks like Bootstrap sets some Margin to auto at some point:

> Additionally, Bootstrap also includes an .mx-auto class for horizontally   centering fixed-width block level content—that is, content that has display: block and a width set—by setting the horizontal margins to auto.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap give the in-build class for design your web.**

***Examples***

```
.mt-0 {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.ml-1 {
  margin-left: 0.25rem !important;
}

.px-2 {
  padding-left: 0.5rem !important;
  padding-right: 0.5rem !important;
}

.p-3 {
  padding: 0.75rem!important;
}
```

***Usage***

```
 <div class="mx-auto" style="width: 200px;">
      Centered element
 </div>
```

**Negative margin**

```
.mt-n1 {
  margin-top: -0.25rem !important;
}
```

***Usage***

```
<div class="row mx-md-n5">
  <div class="col py-3 px-md-5 border bg-light">Custom column padding</div>
  <div class="col py-3 px-md-5 border bg-light">Custom column padding</div>
</div>
```

[For More Reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/spacing/)